# Fatal Error when trying to download addons for GRASS 8.3.1

Tags: grass-gis, error, bash, add-ons

I get an error with `g.extension r.stream.order`:

```
ERROR: Failed to get branch from the Git repository
       <https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/>.
       fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/':
```

I thought this problem was solved in that version.

UPD: If I try to install from local folder, i get this:

```
697s3_k2/r.stream.snap/bin] Error 127
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
Compiling...
make: mkdir: Operation not permitted
make: *** [/usr/local/grass83/include/Make/Rules.make:16: /tmp/grass8- root-7/tmp
```

UPD2: While using command `g.extension -c`:

```
GRASS app > g.extension -c
ERROR: Failed to get branch from the Git repository
<https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/':
getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

UPD3: I checked with version 7.8.7 - addons are installed successfully but only from local folder

Comment: I could install it in G8.3 without problems on Fedora 38. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I use docker container from osgeo/grass-gis:releasebranch_8_3-debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Should add `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` while running the container. Image was OK.

Comment: Do you see a place where this should be documented? Feel free to suggest a text snippet.

Comment: Markus, unfortunately, I am not certain about cases which lead to this issue. Maybe we should simply write a tip providing the error and the solution... I can't ask our DevOps engineer for exact architecture and docker solutions, but I can only suggest that this issue appears when some specific ways of docker images tagging (in git) are used.

Comment: Write a link to documentation file where this could be documented, pls I'll try to add some comments

Comment: All documentation for Docker security setting are located here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you are using docker here.

Fetch latest GRASS GIS 8.3 docker image based on Debian (see [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/download/docker/) for choices):

```
docker pull osgeo/grass-gis:releasebranch_8_3-debian
```

Run the docker image and use `g.extention`:

```
docker run -it osgeo/grass-gis:releasebranch_8_3-debian bash

root@8f88f5c98e9b:/grassdb# grass --tmp-location XY --exec g.extension r.stream.order
Fetching <r.stream.order> from <https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/> (be
patient)...
remote: Enumerating objects: 29, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (26/26), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
remote: Total 29 (delta 0), reused 21 (delta 0), pack-reused 3
Receiving objects: 100% (29/29), 105.74 KiB | 217.00 KiB/s, done.
Already on 'grass8'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/grass8'.
Compiling...
Installing...
Updating extensions metadata file...
Updating extension modules metadata file...
Installation of <r.stream.order> successfully finished
root@8f88f5c98e9b:/grassdb#
```

Looks good...

Comment: I have in my script:

    grass --text $GRASSDATA_PATH/$LOCATION_NAME/PERMANENT --exec sh upgrade_grass.sh

And in upgrade file I have g.extention r.stream.snap

And I have this error:
ERROR: Failed to get branch from the Git repository
       <https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/>.
       fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/':
       getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Comment: In my dockerfile I have
FROM osgeo/grass-gis:releasebranch_8_3-debian

Comment: Markus, I have repeated your command exactly and I got the same error.
ERROR: Failed to get branch from the Git repository
       <https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/>.
       fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/':
       getaddrinfo() thread failed to start