# What is the right way to dissolve vector features in GRASS GIS on attribute values of one column summarizing or averaging others?

Tags: grass-gis, overlay, database, aggregation

The line product of v.overlay contains a column with zones number and a stack of other attributes.

What I want:
Dissolve features (lines) on attribute column that contains zones number. Other attributes should be summed or averaged.
Example:

```
cat a_parameter_1 a_parameter_2 ... b_zone
1    76.77        788               25
4    67.99        900               66
3    79.77        786               25
7    12.99        599               67
......................................
```

Dissolve on b_zone, sum parameter_1, average parameter_2

Resulting number should be connected to database table. Number of features, certainly, will be equal to number in zones map that was previously blayer for v.overlay procedure.

UPD: The question is answered by Anna, but the procedure isn't working properly, so I post another question here
[Why new v.dissolve procedure generates new database tables and causes an error on adding columns later?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475932/why-new-v-dissolve-procedure-generates-new-database-tables-and-causes-an-error-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe v.dissolve in latest GRASS (upcoming 8.4) can do that, see examples on man page: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass84/manuals/v.dissolve.html

Comment: Anna, unfortunately I have to use version 7 for the moment.

Comment: Is it working that way on version 8.3?

Comment: Cannot use version 8.3 and 8.4 because of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474445/fatal-error-when-trying-to-download-addons-for-grass-8-3-1/475078#475078