# Why new v.dissolve procedure generates new database tables and causes an error on adding columns later?

Tags: grass-gis, dissolve

The new v.dissolve procedure includes, as the documentation states, two independent processes: v.reclass and v.extract, being a front end to those.
In my case when v.reclass is called it creates a new table:

```
Building topology for vector map
<over_geo_diss_ef0691c223f2_631@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...

v.reclass complete. 5195 features reclassed.
```

The initial map was over_geo_diss (over_geo map that is to be dissolved).
Due to that new strange table, that is certainly linked to vector now, addcolumn process (that is also included in v.dissolve as it adds new aggregated columns, throws an error:

```
   ERROR: There is no table connected to <over_geo_diss>. Run v.db.connect or
   v.db.addtable first.
   ERROR: A processing step failed. Check the above error messages and see the
   following details:
   Module run `v.db.addcolumn map=over_geo_diss layer=1 columns=LENGTH
   DOUBLE,SOURCE DOUBLE,OUTLET DOUBLE` ended with an error.
```

So it seems that the proccess removes connection between the initial map and all tables during v.reclass stage.

UPD: I've done some experiments with v.reclass and v.extract (like here is mentioned https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.extract.html) and
there is no errors, but
1.the resulting map isn't aggregated, it has the same number of features as the initial, features aren't merged
2. the resulting map contains only cat column and key column (column of characteristic for aggregation) - it doesn't meet the task at all, as all other columns must be preserved and summed or averaged.
So, using v.reclass and v.extract isn't enough for this task.

UPD2: if I switch backend to univar the process suspends after v.reclass and never ends

UPD3: opened a github issue https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/3420

Comment: GRASS GIS ver. is 8.4.0